# Why doesn't checkbox select all not working on Firefox at the first time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview, checkbox

I have a gridview, I've added a Checkbox column.

With checkbox select all, I am using `jQuery` to check all the checkboxes.

Following code is what i have tried,

```
function checkBoxSelectAll() {
     $("#chkSelectAll").click(function () {
          $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
     });
 }
```

I used DevExpress Gridview in MVC5, This is my code in View

```
@(Html.DevExpress()
      .GridView(settings =>
                    {
                        //settings.Settings.ShowVerticalScrollBar = true;
                        settings.Height = Unit.Percentage(100);
                        settings.SettingsPager.Mode = GridViewPagerMode.ShowAllRecords;
                        settings.Settings.ShowFooter = true;
                        settings.Name = "gvw1";
                        settings.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
                        settings.CallbackRouteValues = new
                                                           {
                                                               Controller = "Vehicle",
                                                               Action = "ListPartial"
                                                           };
                        settings.SettingsBehavior.AllowGroup = false;
                        settings.SettingsBehavior.AutoExpandAllGroups = true;
                        settings.KeyFieldName = "Id";
                        settings.Columns.Add("VehicleGroupName", Html.GetResource("group")).GroupIndex = 0;
                        settings.Columns.Add(column =>
                        {
                            column.SetHeaderTemplateContent(content =>
                            {
                                ViewContext.Writer.Write(string.Format("<input type='checkbox' name='chkSelectAll' id='chkSelectAll' onchange='checkBoxSelectAll()'/>"));
                            });
                            column.SetDataItemTemplateContent(c =>
                            {
                                ViewContext.Writer.Write(string.Format("<input type='checkbox' name='chkID' id='" + @c.KeyValue + "' />"));
                            });
                        });
```

Devexpress Gridview generate HTML below

```
<tr id="gvw1_DXDataRow1" class="dxgvDataRow_DevEx">
    <td class="dxgvIndentCell dxgv" style="width:0px;border-left-width:0px;border-bottom-width:0px;">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="gvw1_tccell1_1" class="dxgv" style="border-left-width:0px;">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkID" id="1657">
      </td>
</tr>
```

It works good in Chrome, Safari, Opera, IE11, Microsoft Edge.
But in firefox, at the first time, It doesn't work. (When I click on the checkbox select all, all checkbox in this gridview doesn't checked).
Then I unchecked the Checkbox Select All, then I checked it again, It worked, All checkbox in gridview be checked.

Anyone can tell me why?

I am using `jQuery 1.9.1`.

Sorry for my bad English.

Thanks a lot,

Truong Mai

Comment: Add your complete code, HTML and Javascript, and also when the `checkBoxSelectAll` is called

Comment: `$("#chkSelectAll").click(function () {` need not be there I think.... `function checkBoxSelectAll() {
    var $all = $("#chkSelectAll");
    $('input:checkbox').not($all).prop('checked', $all[0].checked);
}`

Comment: Can include `html` , `js` at Question ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've add my HTML code in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling javascript function `checkBoxSelectAll` for every click on select all checkbox and registering click handler every time. Instead you need to register click handle or change handler only once when document get loaded.

try below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#chkSelectAll").change(function () {
        $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, it should be in `ready`, but OP says it works on other browsers except FF, can you explain why?

Comment: OP registering this click handler inside `checkBoxSelectAll ` function and hence there are multiple click handler get registered for same checkbox which is not necessary. These multiple handlers may be creating issue and browser may not able to identify the handler properly and create mess. Instead OP can register it once when page loads and handler can  work as expected.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar that is logically true... if op is calling the method on an onclick handler... regarding which OP has said nothing about.. then how is it working on other browsers

Comment: I understand and I agree, but `It work good on Chrome, Safari, Opera, IE11, Microsoft Edge. But on firefox, at the first time, It doesn't work.`. How?

Comment: @Tushar, I came accross same issue in past where i was dynamically attaching click handlers when elements loaded and was working on Chrome and IE but not on firefox. So I came to the conclusion that it was problem of multiple handlers. I deregister handlers using `.off()` and then register `.on()` so it works for me. I don't know why it works on chrome but does not work on firegfox.

Comment: Thanks @BhushanKawadkar, I solved my problem with your solution. 
Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

As given above the problem is how you are registering the event handler. You are adding the handler which actually sets the checked property only on change of the `all checkbox`, so when the first click happens the handler which really changes the checked property is not present so it is not fired.

When the second click happens, you have already added a click handler which will add the desired click behavior, but now you are adding an additional click handler so the 3rd click will trigger the jQuery handler twice.

As discussed above the solution is to use a single click handler which is registered in the dom ready handler like

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#chkSelectAll").click(function () {
        $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
})
```

But going back to why it is working in chrome, I think it is because of the choice of event handler you have choose, you are calling `checkBoxSelectAll` in an `onchange` handler, but it looks like the order of `change` and `click` handler order defers in FF and other browsers. In chrome the change event is fired first then the click handlers... so by the time the click handlers are triggered your `checkBoxSelectAll` would have already added the jQuery handlers causing the click to work. But in FF the click handlers is fired first then the change handler so when click is processed there is no jQuery handler.

```js
$("#chkSelectAll").on('click change', function(e) {
  snippet.log('event: ' + e.type)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<input id="chkSelectAll" type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
```